# Compile OpenMP application with target pragma on Nvidia GPU

Tags: openmp

I’m trying to compile and run an application with OpenMP target pragma that checks if it runs on GPU or CPU.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
int runningOnGPU = 0;
/* Test if GPU is available using OpenMP4.5 */
#pragma omp target map(from:runningOnGPU)
{
if (omp_is_initial_device() == 0)
runningOnGPU = 1;
}
/* If still running on CPU, GPU must not be available */
if (runningOnGPU)
printf("### Able to use the GPU! ### \n");
else
printf("### Unable to use the GPU, using CPU! ###\n");

return 0;
}
```

My OS is Ubunto 18.04 LTS, GPU - Quadro P4000, the driver is nvidia-driver-440-server and Cuda version 10.0.

I tried to follow those documents but none of them worked.
https://freecompilercamp.org/llvm-openmp-build/ - segmentation fault with this build command

> clang -fopenmp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda ongpu.c

https://github.com/clang-ykt/clang/wiki - build error

https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/04/building-gcc-with-support-for-nvidia.html - compilation error

https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6510-jeff-larkin-targeting-gpus-openmp.pdf - - compilation error

Where can I find a document with instructions on how to build a simple OpenMP application that runs on GPU?

Comment: Try with GCC 7.1.0 up and follow the steps here https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/04/building-gcc-with-support-for-nvidia.html

Comment: I tried to use this article but I have a compilation error when I compile the source file.